# How do I remove duplicate users from two merged WP_User_Query objects?

Tags: php, search, meta-query, wp-user-query

I'm trying to write a search that makes use of several custom user meta fields I've created, but was having a tough time implementing them. Basically having the same problem [this guy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193765/wp-user-query-will-not-combine-meta-normal-search-methods) was having, and I solved it similarly.

```
              $exclude = array( '1' ); 
              $args1 = array(
                'exclude'        => $exclude,
                'search'         => '*' . $search_query . '*',
                'search_columns' => array(
                  'user_login',
                  'user_nicename',
                  'user_email',
                  'user_url',
                ),
              );

              $args2 = array(
                'exclude'    => $exclude,
                'meta_query' => array(
                  'relation' => 'OR',
                  array(
                    'key'     => 'first_name',
                    'value'   => $search_query,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                  ),
                  array(
                    'key'     => 'last_name',
                    'value'   => $search_query,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                  ),
                  array(
                    'key'     => 'nickname',
                    'value'   => $search_query,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                  ),
                ),
              );

              // queries
              $search_query = new WP_User_Query( $args1 );
              $meta_query = new WP_User_Query( $args2 );

              $user_query = new WP_User_Query();
              $user_query->results = array_merge( $search_query->results, $meta_query->results );

              //populate total_users count for the loop to work correctly
              $user_query->total_users = $search_query->total_users + $meta_query->total_users;
              // Remove duplicate users from array
              /* final step goes here */
```

Now, though, when the search terms overlap with users they have in common, the queries will sometimes return the same result twice. Is there a way I can screen for duplicates?

**Edit**: Here's how I solved the issue.

```
              if (!empty($search_query->results)) {
                foreach ($search_query->results as $user) {
                    $user_info = $user->ID;
                    array_push($exclude, $user_info);
                }
              }
```

Comment: any luck with the solution I posted?

Comment: Just about to get to work implementing it. Great idea. Will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the user IDs found in the first query, as an array, before executing the second query.

Then use that array in the `exclude` value, in the second query args and then run it.

**UPDATE**

How to put the IDs from the first query into an array, to be used in the second query.

You didn't use the `fields` [parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter), hence the query returns everything it finds about users (`all` (default) *Returns an array of [WP_User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) objects*)

```
// Put the found user IDs in an array, after executing the first user query
$exclude = array();
foreach ( $search_query->results as $user ) {
 $exclude[] = $user->ID;
}
```

Now you can successfully use `$exclude` as the value of the parameter `'exclude'`, as you did, in the second query.

Comment: Brilliant. Do you know offhand whether there's a function that exists to pull the list of user IDs in an array from a query?

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know how it goes. I didn't test it, but it should work just fine.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me, but my solution was very similar. Post updated with the info.

Comment: Updated my answer. Simply needed to add ->results (that's where the user results are).